# Beginner jQuery slide show light box error

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="images">
<img alt="" class="show" src="./images/Cars (1).jpg" />
<img alt="" src="./images/Cars (2).jpg" />
<img alt="" src="./images/Cars (3).jpg" />
<img alt="" src="./images/Cars (4).jpg" />

</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript and Css

```
$(function(){
                slideShow();
                $('img').click(function(){
                    $('<div>',{
                        id : "overlay"
                    }).css({'width':'100%' 
                    ,'height':'100%',
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'top':'0',
                    'left':'0',
                    '-z-index':'1',
                    'background' : '#000',
                    'opacity' : '.6'}).appendTo("body");

                    $('<img>',{
                        src : $(this).attr(src)
                    }).css({
                        '-z-index' : '1001',
                        'width':'100%',
                        'height':'100%',
                    }).appendTo("#overlay");
                });
            });
            function slideShow(){
                var current = $('.show');
                var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().first();
                current.hide().removeClass('show');
                next.fadeIn().addClass('show');
                setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
            }
```

The slideshow works properly and the overlay element is added to the body. But the img tag isn't appended to #overlay what is the error?

Comment: Why `-z-index` instead of `z-index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small change to fix this as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        $('<div>', {
            id: "overlay"
        }).css({
            'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'left': '0',
                'z-index': '1',
                'background': '#000',
                'opacity': '.6'
        }).appendTo("body");

        $("#images").appendTo($("#overlay"));

        $('<img>', {
            src: $(this).attr(src)
        }).css({
            'z-index': '1001',
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%'
        });
    });
});

slideShow();

function slideShow() {
    var current = $('.show');
    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().first();
    current.hide().removeClass('show');
    next.fadeIn().addClass('show');
    setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
}
```

Now your #images is appended inside the #overlay.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/jJVcE/)**

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You should append the div element #overlay programmatically inide your img.click function.
`$("body").append($("#overlay"));`

or just put

`<div id="overlay"></div>`

somewhere on your html page.